# Laravel ,font-family works on Ubuntu but not on Debian

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, debian

I have an Problem.

I have coded an Laravel 5 Script on Ubuntu 17 and want use it now on Debian.

But the font font-family is not the same and it looks not good.

On Ubuntu i have installed on my Machine all Fonts i need and add it in my Body CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", Helvetica, Arial;
```

Now i have installed also on Debian the Font files for the System and restart the Browser but the Laravel script dont use it, why? Or have i forget something?

Thanks

Comment: Which Laravel  script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest loading it from Google's CDN as opposed to downloading the font files and installing them on your local machine.

You can achieve this by putting the following code at the top of your CSS file:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono');`